# Displaying data within a date range from a rails scaffold

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, view, controller, scaffold

This is in my controller:

```
@somethings = Something.find(:all)
```

And my count variable would display a break up of this data based on 'rca' as such:

```
@something_to_count = Something.count( :conditions => { :rca => "4X32W"})
@something_to_count2 = Something.count( :conditions => { :rca => "6X36W"})
```

..... etc to other count variables...

Simple as this is, I was trying to get it to display these stats/counts for all entries made from the 'Something' table within the last thirty days in one view and within a date range in another view. I have the default timestamps added by the scaffold function (`created_at` and `updated_at`) in my model.

My view would have to be split up into two pages. One page to accept a date range and display the count variables along with the data in a table and the other page to display just the same for the last thirty days. (i.e. `def last_30_days` and `def within_dates` would be the actions). I found a solution on line which has a date variable subtracted from 30 etc which did not seem to work. A full fledged working solution would be greatly appreciated. Please help. Also, how would I convert a simple date range entry into the same format as the datestamps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create scopes to your querys, so you can reuse them.
My approach to your problem would be something like this:

```
scope :last_30_days, where("created_at between ? and ?", Date.today - 30, Date.today)
scope :within_dates, lambda { |start_date, end_date|
  where("created_at between ? and ?", start_date, end_date)
}
scope :based_on_rca, lambda { |rca|
  where(:rca => rca)
}

@something_to_count = Something.based_on_rca("4X32W").last_30_days.count
@something_to_count = Something.based_on_rca("4X32W").within_dates(Date.today - 4.month, Date.today - 1.month).count
```

Various scopes with small queries that can be chained to reflect on a larger one.
Regards.